# What did the Framers intend the meaning of “probable cause” to be?

Tags: united-states, constitution, history, fourth-amendment

The 4th amendment reads

> The right of the people to be secure in their persons, houses, papers, and effects, against unreasonable searches and seizures, shall not be violated, and no warrants shall issue, but upon **probable cause**, supported by oath or affirmation, and particularly describing the place to be searched, and the persons or things to be seized.

Was it intentionally vague or did it have a clear meaning at the time?

Comment: This question would be better on [law.se] since it’s asking about the historical meaning of a legal term

Comment: I don’t think so because it relates specifically to not simply the meaning of a term, but the history behind it and possibly what the framers discussed about its political implications.

Comment: The meaning is clear if you read carefully. It is the structure of the sentence that confuses many. "... no warrants shall issue, but upon probable cause, .." IMO, it means "no warrant shall be issued without probable cause". Does it makes sense now? But I agree, this question is better asked on the forum for "Law".

Comment: @r13 I’m talking not about the phrasing of the amendment, but the meaning of probable cause.

Comment: You confused me. We obviously can't guess what went through their mind or expect to find the record of their discussion, I think any answer will be highly speculative then.

Comment: @r13 I may be mistaken, but didn’t’ they write a lot of papers about their ideas about the Constitution?

Comment: If there is a record, a web search will bring it up or provide the leads. Here is something, from Cornell Law School, FYI - "Courts usually find probable cause when there is a reasonable basis for believing that a crime may have been committed (for an arrest) or when evidence of the crime is present in the place to be searched (for a search)."

Comment: Both of the existing answers overlook the fact that "probable" originally meant "provable."  An answer that doesn't examine the extent to which this sense of the word was "baked in" to the meaning of the stock legal phrase "probable cause" isn't complete.  One existing answer is based on speculation around the word's modern sense of "likely," but that is not really what the word means in this phrase.  The other answer offers only a citation from a modern etymology reference.  I have voted to reopen the question with the intention of adding a more reasoned answer.

Comment: @TheMamba - *... possibly what the framers discussed about its political implications.* On August 17, 1789, the House considered "the seventh clause of the fourth proposition," which later became the the Fourth Amendment. There was no discussion concerning "probable cause." [Image 783] *See* [Annals of Congress](https://memory.loc.gov/cgi-bin/ampage?collId=llac&fileName=001/llac001.db&recNum=390). The proposed amendments were sent to the Senate; there is no record of their discussion. The proposed amendments, with changes, were returned to the House, approved, and sent to the states.

Answer (score 3):

> *Was it intentionally vague or did it have a clear meaning at the time?*

It was clear. There were 100 years of its use in law, before Congress wrote the amendment.

> As a legal term, **probable cause** "reasonable cause or grounds" is attested from 1670s. [etymology.com](https://www.etymonline.com/word/probable)

In the more that 200 years since, the meaning has not changed.

Answer (score 1):

As with many things in law and politics, the phrase 'probable cause' was not meant to be vague; it was meant to be an interpretable guideline. It strikes a balance between two problematic extremes.

On one hand, we do not want a society where police or federal agents say to themselves:

> Something about Joe Smith is suspicious, and we are going to go root
> around through his stuff until we figure out what illegal thing he's
> doing.

That is prejudicial, invasive, and destructive. It's improbable that even the most virtuous citizen would survive such a draconian investigation unscathed, and that doesn't even address the public shaming, material deprivation, and loss of social status that Joe Smith would suffer as officers spent days or weeks digging up his yard and carrying off his possessions for analysis.

On the other hand, we do not want a society where police or federal agents say to themselves:

> We have really good reason to believe that Joe Smith is engaged in
> criminal activities, but he is committing all of them on his own
> private property, and we can't ever go there. So it seems he's
> scot-free.

That would make it far too easy to get away with criminal activity, merely by keeping it behind closed doors where police can't go.

The compromise is to insist that police and agents have **probable cause** to violate the person's property rights: sufficient evidence to suggest that a *specific* crime is being committed, so that they can justifiably search for and seize further evidence ***only*** where it relates to that specific crime. This prevents police from going on rampant fishing expeditions looking to pin something on someone they have targeted, but allows them to build a case against more intelligent and careful criminals who try to hide their crimes.

The phrase is left underspecified because times and contexts change, so it's impossible to predict what might be sufficient cause in the future. For instance, back when the Constitution was written the Founders had no idea that a thing called 'Twitter' would exist, where people might spontaneously confess that they were planning to commit a crime. They knew they couldn't predict such things and write them specifically into the document, so instead they used a 'reasonable person' standard: that the agency has to convince a reasonable person (usually a judge) that there is a strong circumstantial case that a crime is being committed.